# My facebook page doesn't appear by adding a tab

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add Facebook app in a tab on my page.
I use this url for that : 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

Unfortunately my page doesn't appear in the list.
I'm admin of my page and my app is published (but not submitted).

Comment: what you tried so far??

Comment: I successful published app like tab on another test page;
I had verified that I was admin on the page, in the app

Comment: can you show code so that we can fix it easily??

Comment: It's not a code problem, my app works fine on my site and on other fb page, but I can't add my app on my "finale" page. My page not appear in the selectbox. "Select the Facebook Pages to add MYAPPNAME to [selectbox]"

Comment: can I see the link to your app so that I can inspect

Answer (score 0):

After a quick conversation with a Facebook developer, he redirected to this bug : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331985337005510/

Then I use a little script to add my app on my page (temporaly solution): https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331985337005510/?comment_id=435667956591231